# How to add a click event for images in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following code. Which basically gets all the images from the folder apps and the subfolders of it. My problem is that I am trying to add a click event to all of the images to do the same thing. Basically "`exec("apps/" + apps[app_count] + "/app.py"`)"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pygame import *
import os
import pygame
import time
import random
import sys

_image_library = {}

class SeedOS():

    def home(self):
        (width, height) = (240, 320)
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Seed OS')
        pygame.font.init() 
        Font30 = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30)
        WHITE = (255,255,255)
        BLACK = (0,0,0)
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        apps = os.walk("apps").next()[1]
        app_count = 0
        icon_width = 15
        icon_height = 0
        max_width = 155
        pygame.display.flip()
        while True:
            while app_count < len(apps):
                print apps[app_count]
                image = pygame.image.load("apps/" + apps[app_count] + "/app.png").convert()
                screen.blit(image, (icon_width, icon_height))
                icon_width+=70
                if icon_width > max_width:
                    icon_width = 15
                    icon_height +=70
                app_count += 1
            time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(0,290,240,30))
            clock = Font30.render(time2, False, WHITE)
            screen.blit(clock,(60,288))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.quit()

phone = SeedOS()
phone.home()
```

This is the part of the code that checks all of the things in the folder "apps"

```
while app_count < len(apps):
                    print apps[app_count]
                    image = pygame.image.load("apps/" + apps[app_count] + "/app.png").convert()
                    screen.blit(image, (icon_width, icon_height))
                    icon_width+=70
                    if icon_width > max_width:
                        icon_width = 15
                        icon_height +=70
                    app_count += 1
```

and appends all the images from each folder. I want on every icon click , execute it's "app.py" as in every app folders there are two files: "app.png" and "app.py".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the coordinates of every image in the `apps` list and then use these coordinates with the `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` method :

```
while True:
            while app_count < len(apps):
                print apps[app_count]
                apps[app_count] = (apps[app_count], icon_width, icon_height)  # Adding coordinates to the list
                image = pygame.image.load("apps/" + apps[app_count][0] + "/app.png").convert() # Adding an index to find the image in the tuple
                screen.blit(image, (icon_width, icon_height))
                icon_width+=70
                if icon_width > max_width:
                    icon_width = 15
                    icon_height +=70
                app_count += 1
            time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(0,290,240,30))
            clock = Font30.render(time2, False, WHITE)
            screen.blit(clock,(60,288))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == 1: # MOUSEBUTTONLEFT
                        for a in apps:
                            if a[1] < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < a[1]+IMAGEWIDTH and a[2] < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < a[2] + IMAGEHEIGHT:
                                # Instruction to launch ("apps/" + a[0] + "/app.py")
```

All you have to do is to define is the width and the height from your icons (what you could do with `pygame.Surface.get_size()` if it's not the same for every app) and to replace the last line with the correct syntax. On windows you could use :

```
os.system("apps\\"+a[0]+"\\app.py") # of course you should import os first
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. You saved my day :-)